# フィードアイコン周辺のデザイン崩れ

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

各ページの右下にあるフィードへのリンクについて:

[image: フィード]

1. アイコンの左に何かのラインが見える
2. フィードアイコンとラベルの間が詰まって見える

Google Chrome 37.0.2062.124 / Mac OS X 10.9.5 / Retina